# group concat and sum with left join my sql

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

I have 3 tables

**orders** 
(`id,package_id,rooms`)

**orders_date** (`id,order_id,date`)

**packages** (`id,package_name`)

In orders_date table I have multiple rows for same orders

result I want is as follows

> date(with group_concat) package_name rooms(sum of rooms.. as we'll
>   group by package id)

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: SELECT o.package_id,GROUP_CONCAT(od.confirmed_date) AS confirmed_date,p.`package_name`,SUM(o.`rooms`) AS rooms
FROM `tbl_orders` o
LEFT JOIN `tbl_order_dates` od ON o.`id`=od.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_holiday_packages` p ON p.`id`=o.`package_id`
WHERE o.`flag`='0'
GROUP BY o.`package_id`

Comment: ANYONE WHO CAN SOLVE THIS ISSUE ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if someone requires it.
Below is the query

```
SELECT package_id,rooms,GROUP_CONCAT(od.`confirmed_date`),package_name
FROM 
(
    SELECT o.id,o.package_id,SUM(o.rooms) AS rooms,o.flag,h.`package_name` 
    FROM tbl_orders o 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_holiday_packages` h ON o.`package_id`=h.`id` 
    GROUP BY o.package_id

) o
LEFT JOIN 
tbl_order_dates od ON o.id=od.`order_id`
WHERE o.flag='0'
GROUP BY o.package_id
```